# SBT IO.download(...) method show progress

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT (I am using 0.13.0) there is `sbt.IO` object that provides some helpful methods. One can for example download files from internet like this:

```
sbt.IO.download(new URL(...), file(...))  //my program freezes until end of this method
```

I am writing a sbt plugin and want to download some files from internet. I want to somehow show progress bar during download. That would be nice informing user that program still works showing him some info.

How would you do this?

Comment: Perhaps there's some third party library that does this. I'm pretty sure sbt doesn't have anything for it.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the `sbt-s3` plugin which shows progress.  To do so you need the size of the download.  This requires, I believe, diving deeper into the HTTP APIs than sbt.IO does (which just uses java's URL openStream magikz).  As @SethTissue said, you should probably look for a third party lib that lets you track status, then use the console hooks found in sbt-s3.

Answer (score 0):

As Seth and Josh commented, it's not possible with sbt out of the box.